# One Word for Functions, Variables, and Objects

Tags: javascript, functions, variables

**Is there a single word that can describe JavaScript functions, variables, and objects?**  I was thinking "entities", but that word is usually used to describe the mapping between objects and a database.  And I'm trying to be more descriptive than calling them just "things".  Also, "concepts" or "ideas" seem a bit too abstract...  Is there another word I could use that is more concrete?

For example: "In JavaScript, 'scope' is the set of ____(word)____ you have access to."

The example was taken from [this](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp) article in w3schools, and I was wondering if there is another term that succinctly covers function, variables, and objects.

Comment: In **other** languages, sometimes they are called identifiers (emphasizing the ability to refer to them by name) or symbols (emphasizing the role they play in linking - a step that isn't relevant at all to JavaScript.)

Comment: If I got it right _all_ Javascript ____(word)____ are objects, but anyway.

Comment: @rwong: An "identifier" is the name of the thing, not the named thing.

Comment: In the context, a scope is the set of *identifier bindings* that you have access to.

Comment: Variables are pretty different things from functions and objects. This would be easier to answer if you said what, specifically, you're trying to describe that apparently covers all three categories.

Comment: @delnan:  I was reading an article on w3schools concerning [scope](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp).  In that article it mentions that "in JavaScript, scope is the set of variables, objects, and functions you have access to."  I understand that the article is at a very fundamental level, but I've encountered similar problems before where I try to categorize certain programming language concepts as a way to make learning more feasible.

Comment: @Dash That article is playing fast and loose with terminology. As JacquesB says, scopes concern *identifies* while objects and functions are *values*, a completely separate category of things. For example, one might say "the identifier `x` is in this scope here". But if you previously stored `5` in `x`, then 5 is still just a *value*. It's not something that's included in the scope, that doesn't even make sense. Yeah, you can access it, but only because it's the value of *a variable that's in scope*.

Comment: @delnan  Perhaps _identifier_ could suffice afterall?  "5" is just a symbol for the actual value of 5 that is stored in memory somewhere.  Also, objects and variables are both associated with some kind of identifier.

However, I also see Lightness Races in Orbit's argument.  So, the core of the problem is how do you refer to both the "slot" for the values and the values themselves.  So perhaps there really is no umbrella term that covers all these concepts and only these concepts.  But, I'm willing to take a shot with "identifiers" as long as the context is somehow clear.

Comment: Although the digit `5` is technically an expression and not the value, switching these two is often far less than confusing variables and their values.

Comment: @Dash why do you need this term? For me, it seems like you're just being confused by a haphazardly written article from a site which is known to be full of factual and conceptual mistakes (see http://www.w3fools.com/). AFAIK, there is no umbrella term for those 3 things, but functions and objects together can be simply called "values" (but it depends on a context).

Comment: @scriptin I'm beginning to understand that the explanation is technically wrong, and is probably a loose description just to avoid confusion for beginner-level programmers.  Thank you for pointing out w3fools.com :) I just fail to believe that there is no umbrella term for these concepts...  The reason I am searching for a term is because I personally can understand things more clearly if I categorize and group things in my head into a tree-like structure.  Putting things into groups and categories helps me understand those concepts better...  Judging by the downvotes, I might be the only one

Comment: It is not one word but I would say "imperative code constructs".  I assume you want to set those apart from the markup, the declarative code constructs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no common term (and you don't need one) since they are different categories of things. The quote uses imprecise language:

> In JavaScript, scope is the set of variables, objects, and functions
>   you have access to.

Technically this is wrong, since it confuses *variables* and *values*, which are distinct concepts. A scope is a set of variables. A *variable* is a named reference to a value. Objects, functions and primitives are *values*. So there is a level of indirection between variable and value which mean you cannot lump them together.

Comment: You make interesting points.  I'm wondering then if it is valid to say that these are JS "constructs"??  I'm not sure.  If functions are a kind of object, and an object is a kind of value, and variables contain values, then is there a word that can describe both the value and the "slot"?  If you were to buy shoes at a store you would describe it as just "buying shoes" despite that the item comes with a shoe box ("slot").  But, is it correct to say that variables, objects, and functions are all types of values?

Comment: @Dash: A variable is not a type of value, so no. *Language constructs* or *language element* are broad terms which would encompass both variables and values and many other things.

Comment: Okay, but at least we are getting closer to a possible term.  IMHO, _Language construct_ and _language element_ is better than calling them "things" or "concepts"

Comment: @Dash: My point is you don't *need* a common term for variables and values, since you would never lump them together in a meaningful sentence.

Comment: Okay, lets step back a bit.  I can understand that a JavaScript object is not something that the scope has access to directly unless it is assigned to a variable so that the scope can reference the object by an identifier.  And I can understand that functions are values.  But, why would it not be valid to say that the scope is the set of functions and variables you have access to?  I can see an anonymous function have problems since there is no identifier associated with it, but a named function is definitely something a scope might have access to.

Comment: @Dash: When you define a named function, you are just creating a variable which refer to a function object. So the variable representing the name of the function is in scope, but the function object it refers to is not associated with any specific scope.

Answer (score 1):

"Entities" is a good catch-all term, although it is not widely used because there is not often a reason to refer to such a broad group of things.

Indeed, your proposed quotation is wrong: scope limits visibility of *names of things*, not of named things. So you could say "names", or use the technical term "identifiers".

Comment: I didn't downvote.  I think your answer and the other comments are very helpful.  I was actually debating "entities", but after reading another discussion on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550197/whats-the-difference-between-entity-and-class) and another discussion [here](http://www.cs.sfu.ca/CourseCentral/354/zaiane/material/notes/Chapter2/node2.html) I thought there might be another term that is more suitable.  But, then again, I'm not sure if functions and variables in JavaScript are actually objects...